# Capybara send_keys without sending click event?

Tags: rspec, phantomjs, capybara

It seems that using `send_keys` in Capybara always first fires a `click` element on the given input.

Is there a way to bypass this, e.g. when I know I already have set focus to the input (and for some reason don't want a `click` event to be fired)?

By the way, I'm using PhantomJS.

Comment: Are you using PhantomJS with selenium? or are you using it via Poltergeist?

Comment: Poltergeist with PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poltergeist clicks the element before sending keys to it to ensure it is the element in focus - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/browser.coffee#L365 . As you can see from the code the click is skipped if the element already contains a selection which is defined by https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/browser.coffee#L365 .  So the only supported way to skip the click would be to ensure the selection is already in the element you want to send keys to.

Comment: Thank you. For the records: I succeeded to work around this also by just clicking on the element before the input, then sending `:tab` key.